# Ошибка Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php

Я понимаю, что эту ошибку уже тысячу раз рассматривали. На просторах интернета я нашёл три решения этой ошибки в моём случае.

Есть код в файле

```
    protected function sortArgs($prototype, $args) {
        $keyArgs = array();
        $posArgs = array();

        foreach ($args as $arg) {
            list($key, $value) = $arg;
            $key = $key[1];
            if (empty($key)) {
                $posArgs[] = $value;
            } else {
                $keyArgs[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
```

Ошибка выходит на этой строке `$key = $key[1];`

Варианты исправления ошибки, которые я нашёл

`if(isset($key))$key = $key[1];`

`$key = isset($key[1]) ? $key[1] : null;`

`$Key = $Key[1] ?? null;`

Все три варианта ошибку убирают. Теперь вопрос, какой из этих решений подходит к моей ситуации. php7.4

Любой ваш ответ будет принят во внимание.

Comment: Никакое. Все три "решения" - это втыкание головы в песок. Ошибки надо не "убирать", а **исправлять**

Comment: что делает ваш код? не могу понять зачем вам это `list($key, $value) = $arg;
            $key = $key[1];`

Comment: попробуйте для начала соотнести параметры которые вы в функцию передаете, и то как вы их обрабатываете. а не пытаться угадать что на что исправить

Comment: @Ипатьев: ошибки нужно не допускать ;-)

Comment: // sorts any keyword arguments // TODO: merge with apply arguments это перед кодом было, на вопрос, что делает ваш код?

Comment: Это не ответ, а копипаста. Так-то мы примерно представляем, что должен делать этот код. Вопрос был на понимание, исходя из предположения что это "ваш код". Если код не ваш, и есть уверенность что он по идее правильный, то надо смотреть на исходный массив, почему в нем нету таких элементов